# getting handshake error in flutter while installing packages

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

Not able install new packages in flutter

```
description: A new Flutter project.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.13
```

ERROR MESSAGE -

Running "flutter packages get" in myapp...                               Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
        CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: self signed certificate in certificate chain(handshake.cc:352))
pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...

Comment: Check if the date and time of your computer is correct and try again

Comment: @DigaoParceiro yes it is correct

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/31948 or https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32131